# Session breaking on form submit

Tags: php, session

Users log in, and a session variable is created from their username. The menus on the site are determined by the users status - admins see an admin menu, coaches see a coaches menu, etc. All that works fine.

Things break down when I need to use the `$_SESSION['value']` thing again to pass something from one page to another.  For example, a coach will log in and see a list if his games that he has created.  To edit the games, he selects one game,a variable is then passed to the next page where he can edit the details of the game he selected on the previous page.  the minute the form is submitted on the first page (when he selects the game), its like my session is broken, and I lose all the menus etc.

Other forms on the site that simply add things to the database (users, games, etc) that do not need `$_SESSION` to pass anything work fine.

Is there something obvious I am overlooking? Is there another method of passing info from one page to another that wont break my session?

Comment: Pls provide sample code.

Answer (score 3):

<sup>This sounds like the so often...</sup>

**"oh shit, I forgot to call `session_start ();` before using `$_SESSION`"**

---

But there are of course many other things that might cause this kinda headache.

- check to see that the page your form submits to uses the same (or lower down) sub-domain (if your site uses `www` everywhere but not there, the cookie holding the session info won't be doing it's job).
- check to see that you aren't using https on some parts of your site and http on others
- make sure that the TTL (experiation) of the session cookie is long enough so that the user has time to do the edit (this normally isn't a problem, I have yet to come across it with a default configuration)

Comment: session_start() does appear on every page

Comment: ... but does it appear before you try to access/modify `$_SESSION`? That is what is relevant, also; check out the edit of my post. (I'm typing on my blackberry so I'm not that fast when it comes to writing)

Comment: This is what's included in the head of all my  pages -  neded for menu generation

session_start();
 
 function logged_in() {
  return isset($_SESSION['display_name']);
   
 }
 
 
 
 
 
 function confirm_logged_in() 
 
{
  if (!logged_in()) {
   redirect_to("index.php");
      } 
}

Answer (score 1):

make sure you have session_start() on all your pages; including the one your form is submitting to

Comment: session_start() does appear on every page